# AWS send email with template in pinpoint api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Any example of how to send an email with a pinpoint api template in AWS for Python?

I am trying the example https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pinpoint-email.html#PinpointEmail.Client.send_email but I am not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i use

```
client      =   boto3.client('pinpoint-email', region_name=AWS_REGION)
response = client.send_email(
            FromEmailAddress='SENDER',
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': ['TOADDRESSES']
            },
            Content={
                'Template': {
                    'TemplateArn': TEMPLATE_ARN,
                    "TemplateData": json.dumps(TEMPLATE_DATA)
                }
            }
        )
```